# Updated external content type but connection not updated in central admin

Tags: user-profile-service, external-content-type, bdc, bdc-model

I have an external content type for a sql server view, all working well. I add a new field to the view and save (SPD), in central admin I go to BDC and click on the content type - I can see the added field.

When I want to create a new user profile attribute and map this to the new field in the updated content type I cannot see the new field.

What do I need to do to do this? I tried IISReset and restart timer service.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: if I delete the connection and add it back it has the updated view but is this the right way to do it?